# How can my Java code read OS environment variables?

Tags: java, operating-system, environment-variables

This may be a very simple problem, but I couldn't find an answer googleing and I'm in a rush - so I'd appreciate fast code examples.

I have an environment variable on the OS I would like to read using Java code. I've tried `System.getProperty`, but that only seems to work for the `-D` variables supplied directly for the JVM.

How can my Java code read OS variables?

Comment: seriously? I was here first...

Comment: The other question has a much better answer by today's standards of SO, and it was suggested as duplicate of this. It makes more sense to have duplicate this way. No offence meant in any way.

Comment: none taken, I'm mostly bewildered and amused. Thanks for the explanation. The other question specifically states that this here *accepted* answer does not solve the problem. what makes people think it's the same thing?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try [System.getenv(String name)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String))

Comment: Although if you are still using 1.4 (which has end of lifed, but there's still paid support available), it will throw an Error.

Comment: That doesn´t seem to get the env variables setup in .bashrc or .profile. Does it only load the system environment variables?