# How to write a csv with a comma as the decimal separator?

Tags: python, csv, localization

I am trying to create a european-formatted csv in python. I already set the separator to a semicolon

```
writer = csv.writer(response, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

However, this still uses dot `.` as the decimal separator. What's the correct way to make it use a comma, as is correct for my locale? 
I can't seem to find any way to set it in the docs. (I am using, and would prefer to stick to, the built-in `csv` module)

Comment: What the about the decimal separator from the data source ?

Comment: There's some discussion about this in this link - it may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751157/python-csv-list-separator-based-on-regional-settings

Comment: @AliSAIDOMAR what? I have some python floats, so they don't really have a decimal separator assigned to them, they are numbers. But I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: @emmalg unfortunately this only seems to concern CSV separators, not decimal separators.

Comment: @martineau Please take a look at my edit, I don't think this question is a duplicate of the one you linked.

Comment: @maniexx: Yes, the other question is about reading and yours is about writing. However that is a minor difference, since the solution in either case is to replace the decimal mark character with something else, `'.'` with `','` or vice-versa in the duplicate. The answers to the other question are slightly better, IMO, because they also deal with potential issues when dealing with large numbers with a mixture of the two character in them, as well as describing code that does things in a locale-aware way.

Comment: As stated by OP, **this got marked as a duplicate, but the linked question concerns reading and not writing**.

Comment: Although the solution might be similar, the question is *not* a duplicate!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A little bit hacky way, but it's the best I can think of: convert floats to strings and replace `.` with `,`:

```
def localize_floats(row):
    return [
        str(el).replace('.', ',') if isinstance(el, float) else el 
        for el in row
    ]

for row in rows:
    writer.writerow(localize_floats(row))
```

If you want better localization handling, I suggest you convert all numbers using [`babel.numbers`](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/numbers.html) package.

Comment: Won't they be encoded as strings in the csv? IE quoted and interpreted as strings by other software?

Comment: They won't be quoted as you set `;` as delimiter.

Comment: I don't know how other software will handle such format though. IMO it's easier to output numbers as is and then localize them when you really need that (e.g. in UI).

Comment: Yeah, but the csv is going to be read in excel and such. So that's sadly not an option. And an XLS(x) or some other format which is actually a format is not allowed either.

Comment: Got it. Then just replace dots with commas or use Babel's `format_number` function. It'll work.

Comment: I tested your answer, it works for me. Thanks a lot, and I'll be sure to checkout babel if it turns out I need localization somewhere else. (Right now django handles it for me in most places, so I don't want to add it just for  this one minor functionality)

Comment: If your row is a `dict`:

    def localize_floats(row):
        return dict(
            (key, str(row[key]).replace('.', ',')) if isinstance(row[key], float) else (key, row[key]) 
            for key in row
        )