# Import M2M Empty values imported

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-import-export, django-admin-tools

Using Widget Many to many when importing the result is empty.
Tags do exists in the original model.

See Image.

[import result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS0Af.jpg)

**Excel imported**

```
| provider  | tag             | provider_tag_id |
|-----------|-----------------|-----------------|
| Lionsgate | Planes, Top     |                 |
| FOX       | Houses, Low     |                 |
| Dorcel    | something, else |                 |
```

**Model where the m2m is pointing**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Model where the m2m relationship is**

```
class ProviderTag(models.Model):
    provider_tag_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

**Resource to import**

```
class ProviderTagResource(resources.ModelResource):

provider = fields.Field(
    column_name='provider',
    attribute='provider',
    widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Provider, 'name')
)
tags = fields.Field(
    column_name='tags',
    attribute='tags',
    widget=ManyToManyWidget(Tag, separator=',', field='name')
)

class Meta():
    model = ProviderTag
    fields = ('provider', 'tags', 'provider_tag_id',)
    import_id_fields = ('provider_tag_id',)
```

**Admin.py**

```
 class ProviderTagAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('provider', 'get_tags', 'provider_tag_id')
    search_fields = ['provider',]
    resource_class = ProviderTagResource

    def get_tags(self, obj):
        print(obj.tags)
        return ", ".join([str(p) for p in obj.tags.all()])
admin.site.register(ProviderTag, ProviderTagAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot provide a direct answer but my suggestion would be to get the [example application](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#example-app) running.

You can easily test importing a m2m field.  You would have to define a m2m field on `BookResource` in the `core/admin.py` file:

```py
class BookResource(ModelResource):
    categories = fields.Field(
        attribute='categories',
        widget=widgets.ManyToManyWidget(Category, field='name',
                                        separator='|')
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Book
```

Then you can import a sample file such as:

```
id,name,author,author_email,imported,published,published_time,price,categories
1,book1,,email@example.com,0,2020-07-21,,10.25,Category1|Category2
```

At least if you can prove it is working in the example application, then you can hopefully try to debug your implementation.

Comment: I will Try. Let's see If I find out what's missing.

Comment: Ok. The thing is, This is working when I create a CSV from command line. (Like the one you shared ) When I'm using Excel I got an error.

Comment: Ok. More info here... Import Export test app have the same issue. :(

Comment: It works fine for me using the example above (including xlsx files)

Comment: Using excel is not working for me. I think is something related to regional configuration. Like list separator on windows control panel. I have it in Spain. I've found a way around to 'my' users. Using Google Drive Spreadhseet and then downoading it as xsl it works...

Comment: It seems more related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751157/python-csv-list-separator-based-on-regional-settings.

Comment: without specifying separator parameter the default is `","`  and specifying separator as above, both are not working on `django-import-export==2.8.0` and `django==4.0`

Comment: suggest try django-import-export 3.0 beta and if still a problem raise a github issue

Comment: @MatthewHegarty I figured out why it is not working on my side. the header name for the m2m had "SPACE" after the `,`. This is weird!!!. do that means that a csv with a space after a colon in the header is not a valid csv?

Comment: could you [raise an issue](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/)?  Please give us as much info as you can to reproduce