# How to specify the file path in java which has variable in it's path?

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, akka, config

I have two projects. One at location a and other at b.

Project a needs to load the conf file from project b's directory.
I can't hardcode the path for file which is located in b's directory because If I run this on different machine everymachine's username will be different and path can be different as well.

So I want to do is, everyone sets their conf file path as environment varibale in .bashrc. That way I want to use exported variable path in my java code. Now the question is how do I do that?

---

Following is something similar to what I want to do:

I have one varibale stored in my system at .bashrc as follows:

```
export variableName1=~/path_to_file
```

Now I want to use this variable in java while loading the config file as follows:

```
        Config config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("${variableName1}/path_to_file"));
```

How do I do that?

I tried getting the value of variableName1 as follows:

```
        String value =  System.getProperty("variableName1");
                          OR
        String value =  System.getenv("variableName1");
```

But this returns null value only.

Comment: Do you mean System.getProperty("")?

Comment: Is this all about variable usernames or is even the *home/* part different?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can my Java code read OS environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461018/how-can-my-java-code-read-os-environment-variables)

Comment: I don't quite get what your problem is... Is it loading an environment variable or creating variable paths depending on the current user? Or both?

Comment: loading the environment variable. Because whenever I do System.getenv("variableName1"); or System.getProperty("variableName1"); I get the null value

Comment: @deHaar I have modified the question. Does it help to understand the problem?

Comment: Yes, it helps... But unfortunately, I have no idea why your variable doesn't get read (apart from the obvious ones, like typos or access right issues. Which variables do you get when you read all (available) ones by `Map<String, String> envs = System.getenv();`? `variableName1` is not in that map, is it?

Comment: @deHaar correct. variableName1 is not in that map.

Comment: How are you starting your application? Are you even starting it from a terminal? If not, then the environment variable might not have been set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an [environment variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) so is accessed with

```
String myDirectory = System.getenv("variableName1");
```

Comment: But this one is giving me null value :(

Comment: You can print everything with `System.out.println(System.getenv());` If it's not in there then you have not even loaded the `.bashrc` file

Comment: It's not [printing everything I have set in .bashrc but it seems to print only specific values. Any idea why does it behave that way?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
You need to `export` the variable name in `.bashrc` file for accessing from all terminal.

`export variableName1="~/path_to_file"`

Then restart the computer.

Step 2:

In Java code you can get the value by:

```
 String value =  System.getenv("variableName1");
```

Comment: did that. But it seems it's returning null value only

Comment: try again after restarting your ide and add the double quotation

Comment: No it won't work. I tried different approach. And decided to use another environment variable that I already was using in my project